# How can I check if cells contain one of several values and change another cell if those columns all contain either value

Tags: excel, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have four columns with cells that can have values A or B and I want to change the value of a fifth cell if columns contain either value. 
[Here is an example.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UAbQehYWdmU_M8yvDfVf8_LpZBK7aeZ05UtnlVdZBC8/edit?usp=sharing)

If `I`, `K`, and `O` all contain the value `A` or `B` I want column `P` to say `TRUE`

If `I`, `M`, and `O` all contain the value `A` or `B` I want column `P` to say `TRUE`

If `K`, `M`, and `O` all contain the value `A` or `B` I want column `P` to say `TRUE`

To populate column `P`, column `O` always needs to have a value of A or B, and two of the three columns I K and M have to have either value "A" or "B".

Here is a formula a thought would work, but I cannot figure out how to check if a cell equals one of two values. For example: I2="A" OR "B",  K2="A" OR "B",  O2="A" OR "B"

```
=IF(AND(I2="A", K2="A", O2="A"),"TRUE","")
```

I also tried changing the values `A` and `B` to digits `1` and `2`, and adding them up, but it didn't seem to work properly because i could reach the sum of 3 with only two columns. I apologize if I am not explaining this properly..

```
=IF(AND(K1+M1>=2,N1>=85),"TRUE",IF(AND(I1+M1=2,N1>=85),"TRUE",IF(AND(K1+I1=2,N1>=85),"TRUE","")))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are number of way to do it. My solution is to use COUNTIF, assuming that neither "A" or "B" would never appear in column J,L,N.

```
 =AND(COUNTIF(I2:M2,"A")+COUNTIF(I2:M2,"B")>1, OR(O2="A", O2="B"))
```

Comment: Thank you. No, columns J, L, and N will never have A or B. I don't think I explained it properly.  As long as column O has a value of A or B, and two of the three columns I, K, and M contain the value A or B, then column P should populate. So in the example I sent, every column except the bottom two should show TRUE.

Comment: Wait.. I think I messed up and was calculating the row below.

Comment: Hey this works. Thank you so much. I want to fully understand the formula. What does the >1 do?  Is it saying if the count of values in those cells is greater than 1 and O2 is A or B than show TRUE?

Comment: The ">1" means that total number of "A" or "B" are >1 (i.e. at least 2).  If you need exactly 2 out of I,K,M are equal to "A" or "B", then, replace the ">1" in the formula with "=2".

Comment: Say i wanted to count only Bs or only As, could i use the same method?

Comment: For example if column `O`  shows "B" and any two of columns `I` `K` and `M` contain B then show true.

Comment: Then, the formula would reduced to  `=AND(COUNTIF(I2:M2,"B")=2,  O2="B")`

Comment: Thank you. You are amazing.